# WhatsApp delete recording Animation in Android

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I want to implement whatsapp like delete animation as this ios library here 
https://github.com/RATTLESNAKE-VIPER/GLMoveToTrashAnimation

I have searched a lot for it but could not found anything useful.
Please Help
Thanks.

Comment: if I understand you , you need import the same lib to android , even its not question but you can have a look here 
https://android-arsenal.com/ we will not searching for you

Comment: It can be any lib or anyother link for help. Before posting question here I have checked android arsenal.

Comment: may be you need to have a look here https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui

Comment: @MinaFawzy not helpful

Comment: sir , you will need to build it from scratch as I have see something like this lib in android before

Comment: @MinaFawzy I just need an idea how can i achieve it after that I will do it